# WebResource with invalid resources

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, webresource.axd, webresource

In our intranet environment, the website works well, without problems.
Same address, accessed from outside, have the following result at the end of the WebResource.axd return:

```
/* START  */
/* Skipped loading 15 invalid resources. */
/* END  */
```

The WebResource.axd does have content (scripts). This error is shown at the end. I noticed the only included script was MicrosoftAjax.js, no other script were loaded.
Therefore, the WebResource.axd is much smaller than it was supposed to be and, of course, the website is not working (many Javascript functions are not working). But it works when accessed internally. Same server, same WebResource request (URL).

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was using Telerik RadScriptManager. Looks like there is a bug, and it was reported to them.
I had to change to regular ASP ScriptManager. Alternatively, you can use EnableScriptCombining = False in RadScriptManager.